# mod_rewrite or path_info for clean URLs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, pathinfo

I have always used mod_rewrite for creating clean looking URLs, until recently I didn’t know there was any other option. A few weeks back someone on here pointed out that exactly the same effect can be achieved using apache `PATH_INFO`. Thinking about it now, I assume this is what most PHP frameworks do, optionally relying on mod_rewrite purely to remove the `index.php` bootstrap from the URL.

All leads to a few questions:

1. Which is the better way of creating a clean and flexible URL structure like:
   `/page/var/foo/bar/2`?
2. What are the relative advantages/disadvantages of the two methods?
3. Which method peforms better in terms of resource usage etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with pathinfo you will always have script name in the url, which looks pretty lame (and not considered valid by some agents). I'd suggest mod_rewrite as primary method with pathinfo or 404 handler as fallbacks.

Comment: pretty sure i've seen path_info examples without script name in URL, can anyone confirm?

Comment: I'd say it's not possible, but I've been wrong before. However, using `mod_rewrite` to simply redirect all requests to a script and using `path_info` in that script is very possible and to my understanding very common.